# How to stop log4j2 load class in exception stack?

Tags: java, log4j, classloader, log4j2

Log4j2 will load class when print exception stack trace, but it will use the incorrect class loader(**org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader**, extends URLClassLoader, load class synchronized) to load the class generated by aop (such as **sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor<\digit>**, only can load by DelegateClassLoader), and it can never load successfully.

Here is the exception stack trace in my service:

```
2018-11-30 14:43:09.425 - - [ERROR] com.myservice.mobile.message.group.deal.RPCGroupDealService-2-thread-30 ThriftServerInvoker #XMDT#{__ptTest__=true __traceId__=4869019290298993826}#XMDT# mtthrift server invoker Exception:null, cause:
Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: com.alibaba.druid.pool.GetConnectionTimeoutException: wait millis 50, active 20, maxActive 20
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnectionInternal(DruidDataSource.java:1155)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnectionDirect(DruidDataSource.java:977)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:957)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:947)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:102)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource.getConnectionOrigin(SingleDataSource.java:212)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource.access$000(SingleDataSource.java:31)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource$2.getSingleConnection(SingleDataSource.java:197)
at com.mycompany.zebra.filter.wall.WallFilter.getSingleConnection(WallFilter.java:120)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource$2.getSingleConnection(SingleDataSource.java:195)
at com.mycompany.zebra.filter.DefaultJdbcFilter.getSingleConnection(DefaultJdbcFilter.java:75)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource$2.getSingleConnection(SingleDataSource.java:195)
at com.mycompany.zebra.filter.DefaultJdbcFilter.getSingleConnection(DefaultJdbcFilter.java:75)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource$2.getSingleConnection(SingleDataSource.java:195)
at com.mycompany.zebra.filter.DefaultJdbcFilter.getSingleConnection(DefaultJdbcFilter.java:75)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource$2.getSingleConnection(SingleDataSource.java:195)
at com.mycompany.zebra.monitor.filter.CatFilter.getSingleConnection(CatFilter.java:114)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource$2.getSingleConnection(SingleDataSource.java:195)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource.getConnection(SingleDataSource.java:201)
at com.mycompany.zebra.single.jdbc.SingleDataSource.getConnection(SingleDataSource.java:184)
at com.mycompany.zebra.group.datasources.LoadBalancedDataSource.getConnection(LoadBalancedDataSource.java:114)
at com.mycompany.zebra.group.datasources.LoadBalancedDataSource.getConnection(LoadBalancedDataSource.java:80)
at com.mycompany.zebra.group.jdbc.GroupConnection.getReadConnection(GroupConnection.java:176)
at com.mycompany.zebra.group.jdbc.GroupConnection.getRealConnection(GroupConnection.java:192)
at com.mycompany.zebra.group.jdbc.GroupPreparedStatement.executeQuery(GroupPreparedStatement.java:140)
at com.mycompany.zebra.group.jdbc.GroupPreparedStatement.execute(GroupPreparedStatement.java:97)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:39)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:55)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:243)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:117)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:79)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:73)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:350)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.selectList(Unknown Source)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:190)
at com.myservice.mobile.group.biz.domain.dao.DealPoiDao.selectByPoiidsAndDpStatus(DealPoiDao.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
at com.myservice.deal.aspects.aj.MonitorAspect.wrap(MonitorAspect.java:72)
at com.myservice.deal.aspects.aj.MonitorAspect.wrapMethod(MonitorAspect.java:41)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
at com.myservice.mobile.group.biz.common.aspect.DaoFlowControlAspect.doFlowControl(DaoFlowControlAspect.java:25)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.selectByPoiidsAndDpStatus(Unknown Source)
at com.myservice.mobile.group.biz.service.PoiDealService.getPoiDealFromDB(PoiDealService.java:118)
at com.myservice.mobile.group.biz.service.PoiDealService.getPoiDealMap(PoiDealService.java:91)
at com.myservice.mobile.group.octo.DealThriftProcessor.listDidByEqualsPoiidsAndDpStatus(DealThriftProcessor.java:283)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
at com.myservice.deal.aspects.aj.MonitorAspect.wrap(MonitorAspect.java:72)
at com.myservice.deal.aspects.aj.MonitorAspect.wrapMethod(MonitorAspect.java:41)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.listDidByEqualsPoiidsAndDpStatus(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.myservice.mobile.mtthrift.proxy.ThriftServerInvoker.invoke(ThriftServerInvoker.java:187)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.listDidByEqualsPoiidsAndDpStatus(Unknown Source)
at com.myservice.mobile.message.group.deal.RPCGroupDealService$Processor$listDidByEqualsPoiidsAndDpStatus.getResult(RPCGroupDealService.java:726)
at com.myservice.mobile.message.group.deal.RPCGroupDealService$Processor$listDidByEqualsPoiidsAndDpStatus.getResult(RPCGroupDealService.java:715)
at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
at com.myservice.mobile.mtthrift.proxy.ThriftServerPublisher$MtTProcessor.process(ThriftServerPublisher.java:416)
at com.myservice.mobile.mtthrift.server.netty.DefaultServerHandler.handleRequest(DefaultServerHandler.java:138)
at com.myservice.mobile.mtthrift.server.netty.DefaultServerHandler$1.run(DefaultServerHandler.java:106)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When massive exceptions occurred suddenly, worker thread will blocked on the log4j2 class loader load the GeneratedMethodAccessor<\digit>.

Here is my worker thread stack locked on the method loadClass:

[image]

Comment: can you add the full exception stack trace ?

Comment: @dush I have added some details for my question :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the class loading that happens while formatting "extended stack traces", which appears as `ThrowableProxy.toExtendedStackTrace` in your example.

You can disable extended stack traces by adding `alwaysWriteExceptions="false"` to your PatternLayout (and then adding your own exception formatter, such as `%ex`, instead), e.g.:

```
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601}{GMT} %m%n%ex" alwaysWriteExceptions="false"/>
```

I have verified that this fixes the problem for me.

Note that not only does this problem cause locking, it can also cause poor performance due to the JAR unzipping that happens inside e.g. Tomcat's classloader.